# Canvas drawImage() with image doesn't draw anything

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to change all images src of document to dataURL.

I am trying to draw all image in canvas through for of loop but it doesn't work.
Help me!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="./adudio1.png" alt=""height="300px"width="200px"class="i">
    <img src="./adudio1.png" alt=""height="300px"width="500px"class="i">

    
</body>
<script>
    const img = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    for(items of img){
        let c = document.createElement("canvas");
        document.querySelector("body").append(c);
        c.height=items.height;
        c.width=items.width;
        c.style="border:2px solid #CCC;";
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(items,0,0)
  
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it's not working?"

Comment: why don't you just change the `src` attribute of `<img>` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't waiting for the images to load. Add your canvas drawing code to the `onload` function of each image to execute it only once the image data arrives.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

for (const image of images) {
  image.onerror = function () { 
    console.error("image failed to load"); 
  };
  image.onload = function () {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.height = image.height;
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.style = "border: 2px solid #CCC;";
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  };
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" 
     alt=""
     height="300"
     width="200" 
     class="i"
>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" 
     alt=""
     height="300"
     width="200" 
     class="i"
>
```

As an aside, `height="300px"width="500px"` needs spaces between properties and doesn't need `px` after each value.

Use `const item` rather than `items` to avoid creating a global in your loop.